# AngularJS - How to unsynchronize $viewValue and $modelValue in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular JS 1.5.6 and I would like to programmaticaly unsynchronize $viewValue and $modelValue, I want $viewValue to keep its current value but $modelValue to be set to undefined. I tried `modelCtrl.$modelValue = undefined` but it doesn't work.

Here is the code of my directive

```
function blurFocusDirective() {
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elm, attrs, modelCtrl) {
    elm.on('blur', function() {
      console.log('capture blur event');          
      modelCtrl.$modelValue = undefined;
    });
  }
};}
```

I have [plunkered](https://plnkr.co/edit/9XtWbzw6YfNGvNWQgu2Z?p=preview) my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fix by replacing `modelCtrl.$modelValue = undefined;` by `ngModel.$setViewValue(undefined);`